# Ruby on Rails 4, store session in separate database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 rails applications (version 4.0 and 4.1) which have their own database and a secound db-connector to the other database. Both apps have a login-form and now I want to share the session.

In both apps I added the activerecord-session_store gem and in the config/initializers/seesion_store.rb file I set session_store to active_record_store.

How can I tell one app that it use the other database (not the default db-connector) to store the session?

Is there a way to share sessions with cookies? Both apps have different URLs.

I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Your comment / answer was really helpful. Took a lot of googling to find. Would be better if you resubmitted as an answer to your own question IMO. Anyway thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You may override the session store class with your own class and have the functionality to write and read sessions from your second database.

Example class:

> https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/blob/master/lib/active_record/session_store/sql_bypass.rb

Here, you can have `connection` return your second db connection.

***Referring to doc:***

> https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

You may provide your own session class implementation, whether a feature-packed Active Record or a bare-metal high-performance SQL store, by setting

```
ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore.session_class = MySessionClass
```

You must implement these methods:

```
self.find_by_session_id(session_id)
initialize(hash_of_session_id_and_data, options_hash = {})
attr_reader :session_id
attr_accessor :data
save
destroy
```

The example SqlBypass class is a generic SQL session store. You may use it as a basis for high-performance database-specific stores.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I solved this problem with only one line the config/enviroments.rb `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.establish_connection("secound_db_#{Rails.env}")`